Is it possible to programmatically scroll to a specific attributedString in scrollView?
I am developing a Quran application using React Native, but for implementing scrolling, I am using a native SwiftUI component. I need to scroll a ScrollView to a specific Ayah using ScrollViewReader.
My structure looks like this:
ScrollViewReader > ScrollView > LazyVStack > VStack > AttributedText(View) > TextViewWrapper(UIViewRepresentable) > TextView(UITextView)
Currently, I can only scroll to pages, but I need to scroll to a specific Ayah. My code for scrolling looks like this:
  func scrollToAyah(surahIndex: Int, ayahIndex: Int) {
      if let page = quran.pages.first(where: { $0.ayahs.contains(where: { $0.surahIndex == surahIndex && $0.index == ayahIndex }) }) {
        scrollManager.scrollToID = page.id
      }
  }

I attempted to scroll to a specific Ayah using ScrollViewReader by setting scrollManager.scrollToID to the Ayah's ID, as shown in my scrollToAyah function. I expected the ScrollView to scroll directly to the Ayah, but instead, it only scrolls to the page containing the Ayah.
minimal reproducible example:
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")

struct StrPage: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString
}


class ScrollManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var scrollToID: UUID?
}

struct MyView: View {
  @ObservedObject var scrollManager: ScrollManager
  let pages: [StrPage] = [
    StrPage(attributedString: attributedString),
    StrPage(attributedString: attributedString),
    StrPage(attributedString: attributedString),
    StrPage(attributedString: attributedString),
    StrPage(attributedString: attributedString),
    StrPage(attributedString: attributedString),
    ]
  @State private var pageNumberInput: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
          TextField("Enter page number", text: $pageNumberInput)
              .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
              .keyboardType(.numberPad)
              .padding()
          
          Button(action: {
              scrollToPageNumber()
          }) {
              Text("Go")
          }
          .padding()
      }
      .padding(.top,150)

      ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
          LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
              ForEach(pages) { page in
                AttributedText(page.attributedString)
                  .frame(height: 200)
                  .id(page.id)
            }
          }
        }
        .onChange(of: scrollManager.scrollToID) { id in
          if let id = id {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .top)
              scrollManager.scrollToID = nil
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .background(Color(backgroundColor))
  }

  func scrollToPageNumber() {
      guard let pageNumber = Int(pageNumberInput),
            pageNumber > 0,
            pageNumber <= pages.count else {
          return // Не действительный номер страницы
      }
      
      // Прокрутка до страницы с указанным номером
      let page = pages[pageNumber - 1]
      scrollManager.scrollToID = page.id
  }
}

struct TextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
  var attributedText: NSAttributedString
  var maxLayoutWidth: CGFloat

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> TextView {
    let uiView = TextView()

    uiView.backgroundColor = .clear
    uiView.textContainerInset = .zero
    uiView.isEditable = false
    uiView.isSelectable = false
    uiView.isScrollEnabled = false
    uiView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    uiView.delegate = context.coordinator

    return uiView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: TextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.attributedText = attributedText
    uiView.maxLayoutWidth = maxLayoutWidth
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: TextViewWrapper

    init(_ parent: TextViewWrapper) {
      self.parent = parent
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
      textView.selectedTextRange = nil
    }
  }
}

final class TextView: UITextView {
  var maxLayoutWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
      guard maxLayoutWidth != oldValue else { return }
      invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
  }
  
  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    guard maxLayoutWidth > 0 else {
      return super.intrinsicContentSize
    }
    
    return sizeThatFits(
      CGSize(width: maxLayoutWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    )
  }
  
  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
  }
}

struct AttributedText: View {
  private let attributedText: NSAttributedString
  
  init(_ attributedText: NSAttributedString ) {
    self.attributedText = attributedText
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      TextViewWrapper(
        attributedText: attributedText,
        maxLayoutWidth: geometry.size.width
      )
    }
  }
}


Based on the code you provided, don’t you expect to scroll to the page?

it scrolls to the page that contains the verse, but I need it to always scroll exactly to the verse

Please provide a [example], see also [ask].
